# What is the future of playframework 2 in terms of web-templating and MV*

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, template-engine, spray

I have heard that Play Framework 2 will go to use [spray](http://spray.io/) instead of [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). Spray itself believes that

> "The recent trend of moving web application logic more and more away
>   from the server and into the (JS-based) browser client as well as the
>   increasing availability of good SBT-plugins for things spray itself
>   does not provide (like view-templating or LESS- and
>   CoffeeScript-Support) "

Does it mean that playframework will be using javascript [MV*](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/) by default instead of [scala template](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates)?

The philosophic point of `scala` - to provide a scalable (unique) language for big range of use-cases - like web-services, logic, web. But WEB itself goes very close with `Javascript` and `HTML` and frameworks around it.

People tend to save processors time (money) on its cloud boxes, and would probably choose to use client-side computation vs server side, when it's possible.

That's the background of this question - where the Play Framework goes about it?

Should it use `scala` that would compile to `javascript` (for example)?

Comment: You should ask this at the google group

Comment: Ok. Since Spray became a become part of Akka. Now I know answer.